# Cannot cast from double to int

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I was working with a small piece of code in Sharepoint, that goes like this:

```
int? do_ = (int?)re["mi"]; // consider "re" a dictionary<string, object>;
```

The expression to the right of the equal sign evaluates to a `Double`. To make `double` sure, I `double`-checked it (:D) in the watch window. And yeah, it's a `System.Double`, in and out.

However, that line throws an exception:

> Specified cast is not valid.

I was about to make a dent on my desk with my forehead when it dawned on me that yes, you can cast double to int, though losing the non-integer part of the value (which is actually intended in my case). I learned this in my first days of programming, before the world moved on.

So to be even more sure, I created another solution, a simple console app. I put this code into it:

```
double dragon = 2.0;
int? i = (int?)dragon;
```

And it works, just as expected.

Why would it work in one setting but fail in the other one?

Comment: Well. I know you're fibbing somewhere: there is no such thing as `object?`.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance sorry, fixing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very frequently asked question. You cannot *unbox a boxed `T`* to anything other than `T` or `T?`.

I explain why here:

http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/

Comment: Even this question being duplicate, your article is a great resource. Congrats!

Answer (score 2):

But this should work for you

```
(int?)(double)re["mi"];
```

**Edit1**
Above code will work if boxed type is double and doesn't work if it is `double?` 
to make it work do the following

```
(int?)(double?)re["mi"];
```

Comment: Don't you think it should be `(int?)(double?)re["mi"]` - if the `object` reference is not a box with a `double` but actually a `null` reference, you need nullables all the way. Maybe inefficient, though.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yeah but in question he mentioned that it was a double

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: First off, this is unlikely to be the bottleneck. Second, Roslyn does a pretty good job of optimizing nested lifted conversions, though the original-recipe C# compiler is less good. See my series of articles http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/ describing how the nullable arithmetic optimizer works. Part for in particular is germane.

Comment: @EricLippert I don't think it will be a bottleneck either. But I might still write `object reMi = re["mi"]; int? do = reMi == null ? (int?)null : (int)(double)reMi;`. You never know with the "original-recipe" compiler ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you trying to cast object into integer. your decimal value is boxed.

Conciser this:

```
object o = 2.0d;

int i = (int)((double) o); // This will work
```