# Windows Phone - Color.FromArgb() invalid cast

Tags: c#, casting

I have an app which pull the ARGB values of background color from a Isolated storage setting; where I have given the values in int datatype. however the color.fromargb() requires byte datatype but when i cast it, it gives an exception "invalid cast"

here is the exception code:

```
backcolor.Color = Color.FromArgb((byte)dailyspring_settings["back_color_a"],(byte)dailyspring_settings["back_color_r"], (byte)dailyspring_settings["back_color_g"], (byte)dailyspring_settings["back_color_b"]);
```

the isolated storage code

```
dailyspring_settings.Add("back_color_a",100 );
dailyspring_settings.Add("back_color_r",103 );
dailyspring_settings.Add("back_color_g",158 );
dailyspring_settings.Add("back_color_b",236);
```

Comment: You need double-casting: `(byte)(int)dailyspring_settings["back_color_a"]`.

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov, Thank you, double casting works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ulugbek Umirov pointed out, the fix is to "double cast".

Imagine that `s` represents the expression `dailyspring_settings["back_color_b"]` such that the type of the expression is typed as `object`, and the object that it evaluates to is an `int` (System.Int32).

Thus to first go from `object->int` is done with the following [*Type Cast*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx). A Type Cast changes the type of the *expression* or "view" of the object, but it *does not* change or create a new object - as such it will fail with an InvalidCastException if `s` does not evaluate to a `int` (System.Int32) value.

```
int i = (int)s;
```

Now, having an expression typed `int`, the next step is `int->byte`. This is done with a *Type Conversion* defined between an expression and a byte. The result is a *new value*, the byte.

```
byte b = (byte)i;
```

So, as suggested, putting it all together:

```
(byte)(int)dailyspring_settings["back_color_a"]
```

---

The above usages of "Type Cast" and "Type Conversion" are to illustrate a point; see the following questions for technical details and terminology.

- [Casting a boxed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312731/casting-a-boxed-value)
- [Cannot cast from double to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663735/cannot-cast-from-double-to-int)
- [Is casting the same thing as converting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143997/is-casting-the-same-thing-as-converting)
- [What is the difference between casting and conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166840/what-is-the-difference-between-casting-and-conversion?lq=1)